# How to get latest values in table with Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a table like the following:

```
date       | person | assignment
-----------+--------+-----------
2019-01-01 | joe    | blue
2019-02-01 | joe    | red
2019-01-01 | mel    | green
2019-03-01 | mel    | yellow
2019-02-01 | drew   | blue
```

And I want the following result with a Spark query

```
latest     | person | assignment
-----------+--------+-----------
2019-02-01 | joe    | red
2019-03-01 | mel    | yellow
2019-02-01 | drew   | blue
```

I know I could just do `person, max(date) latest` and then query the full list again. But is there an easy way to do this with a Spark windowing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.withColumn(
    "num",
    row_number() over Window.partitionBy("person").orderBy(desc("date")))
  .filter($"num" === 1)
  .drop("num")
  .show()
```